# JavaScript key.classList.add problems

Tags: javascript

I'm creating Vanilla js drum kit, js classList.add not working, I tried to use different attributes, maybe you could help me, or just give some suggestions.

HTML:

```
    <div class="keys">
                    <div data-key="65" class="key">
                      <kbd>A</kbd>
                      <span class="sound">clap</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="83" class="key">
                      <kbd>S</kbd>
                      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="68" class="key">
                      <kbd>D</kbd>
                      <span class="sound">kick</span>
                    </div>
</div>

                  <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
                  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
                  <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
```

JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if(!audio) return; //stop function from running all together
    key.classList.add("playing");
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
 });

function removeTransition(e) {
   if(e.propertyName !== "transition") return;
   this.classList.remove("playing");
}

 const keys = document.querySelectorAll(".key");
 keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener("transitioned", removeTransition));
```

Comment: Your problem is not in classList, it is in your use of `this`

Comment: **Typo:** there is no `<key>` element in your code that could get targeted by your selector. (you forgot a `.` => `document.querySelector(\`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]\`)`)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace key with div in your query string:

wrong:

```
const key = document.querySelector(`key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```

right:

```
const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these corrections:

wrong:

```
const key = document.querySelector(`key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```

right: add period before 'key' since it's a class

```
const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```

add: key.classList.add("playing");

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if (!audio) return;
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    key.classList.add("playing");
});
```